# localStorage for phonegap will store stuff after exiting application?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

How can I use localStorage to store  login credentials for my application? I'm thinking it will store it somewhere when I exit the app, and then when I open the application again the fields will be prefilled with the information from localStorage. Here is my code so far.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
         alert("ready");
         var email = window.localStorage.getItem("email");
         var password = window.localStorage.getItem("password");

         document.getElementById("email").value = email;
         document.getElementById("password").value = password;      
    }

    //If checkbox gets checked then save credentials, if unchecked then forget
    function rememberMe() {
        if(document.getElementById('remember_me').checked) {
            alert("checked");
            window.localStorage.setItem("email", document.getElementById("email").value);
            window.localStorage.setItem("password", docuement.getElementById("password").value);
        }
        else {
            alert("unchecked");
            window.localstorage.clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, the fields doesn't get prefilled with the info from localStorage after I exit and open the app again.

Comment: Code seems working, try to test in desktop browser and debug the execution, may be flow is incorrect.

Comment: Seems to be working now, I had some syntax errors.

Comment: Head's up: localStorage is backed by a sqlite database that is /user-readable/ on many platforms (including iOS). If you must use localStorage for this, better to store a username and authorization token (obtained from your server upon a successful login) so that the token can be revoked at some point the future if needed (or after a set amount of time). Or, investigate using iOS's keychain for storing sensitive information (which, while not perfectly secure, is far better than localStorage). There's a plugin on the Cordova plugins repo that makes this really simple.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage can hold object´s data until it gets removed from the same, but sessionStorage will clear the data when you close the tab/browser.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is use **webSQL** or **SQLite** database. save credentials when anybody tries to login and then when someone opens the app, fill the boxes by reading data from database on pageload or device ready function.